# Test all files in Test directory with Pytest and Tox

Tags: python, pytest

I could execute pytest with Tox(Just type "tox" in terminal from Pycharm) successfully.
But when I typed `pytest -s tests` in Terminal from Pycharm , Then Test was not executed.`ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.`

Even though you can see  `commands = pytest -s tests` in `tox.ini` below and test was succeed in Tox, Then why I couldn't execute `pytest -s tests` in Terminal??

**Directory Structure**

```
root
| - .tox
| - robotor # include all of source code in "robotor" directory
| - tests
| | | - unittest
| | | | - robotor
| | | | | - __init__.py
| | | | | - test_robotor.py
| | | | - __init.py
| | | - __init__.py
| - main.py
| - setup.py
| - setup.cfg
| - tox.ini
```

**tox.ini**

```
    [tox]
    envlist = py37

    [testenv:py37]
    deps = pytest
    commands = pytest -s tests  # I put test files in "tests" directory
```

**setup.cfg**

```
[aliases]
test=pytest
[tool:pytest]
python_files=tests/*
```

**setup.py**

```
setup(
    ~
　　~
    setup_requires=[
        'pytest-runner',
    ],
    tests_require=['pytest'],
　　~
    ~
)
```

Comment: So what happens if you execute it? Does it find no tests? Have you tried `python -m pytest -s tests`?

Comment: @ MrBean Bremen  
This is the Error ``ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.`` and This ``python -m pytest -s tests``  also return same error

Comment: Maybe you are not in the correct virtual environment. Tox installs it's own environments for each Python version, and runs the tests in them, but if you run pytest on the command line you need to be in an environment where all requirements are installed. Check the environment used by PyCharm.

Answer (score 1):

The default working dir for tox is `toxinit`, can you try changedir to `tests`.

Reference here: https://tox.readthedocs.io/en/latest/config.html#conf-changedir

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to run `python setup.py develop`.
Cause when you run TOX it's installing your project inside tox virtualenv. You need to do same thing for your local virtualenv (if you use it, I recommend).

I would recommend you to create local virtualenv with pycharm (PyCharm->File->Settings->Project->Python Interpreter->Add) and then when you run Terminal inside PyCharm you will be inside this virtualenv. The `python setup.py develop`.
With this you can run tests localy with PyCharm (right click on tests and just run). But first choose in settings pytest as tests freamwork in PyCharm.

If you want to integrate Tox and PyCharm to work togheter and run tox tests inside PyCharm I wrote a blogpost about it [here](https://lukeonpython.blog/2020/10/tox-pycharm-integration/).